# Is there any way for React to use any variable outside project so that Docker builds React project from caching once it is built?

Tags: reactjs, docker

Whenever I try to dockerize the React project, if any changes occured in the project, docker re-builds the image from the beginning, which means that it does not use cache. I just change an URL inside the project in general but at each time, image is re-built without using cache so it takes too much.

Is there any trick I can use?

I thought that outside the project, I place any JSON or JS file where I registered the URL so that Docker re-builds the image using caching. Is that possible?

Comment: you can use .env files for that. Those can be passed to the docker image as well
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: I will try but I think changing .env file will prevent from using cache